# Im trying to create binary tree structure of processes where each process has no more than 2 children

Tags: c++, operating-system

Im trying to create two children for each process(binary tree) and if n=3 the process tree structure should be like (1)->(2),(1)->(3),(2)->(4),(2)->(5).I have written a program where in i am able to create 2 processes for a prent process and 2 process for each child process but I want to provide a number n=number and create the processes based on the number passed in binary Tree format.
    Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int foo(const char *whoami) {
    printf("I am a %s.  My pid is:%d  my ppid is %d\n", whoami, getpid(), getppid() );
    return 1;
}

int func() 
{
    int pid = fork(); 

    if (pid==0) { 
        foo("child");

        int pid2 = fork(); 

    if (pid2==0) { 
        foo("child");


        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 
    int pid3 = fork(); 

    if (pid3==0) { 
        foo("child");


        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 

    int pid1 = fork(); 

    if (pid1==0) { 
        foo("child1");

        int pid4 = fork(); 

    if (pid4==0) { 
        foo("child");


        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 

    int pid5 = fork(); 

    if (pid5==0) { 
        foo("child");


        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
       wait(NULL);
    } 
    return 0;   
}


int main()
{
foo("parent");
func(); 
    return 0;
}
output :
```

I am a parent.  My pid is:37  my ppid is 18
I am a child1.  My pid is:38  my ppid is 37
I am a child2.  My pid is:39  my ppid is 38
I am a child3.  My pid is:40  my ppid is 38
I am a child4.  My pid is:41  my ppid is 37
I am a child.  My pid is:42  my ppid is 41
I am a child5.  My pid is:43  my ppid is 41

Comment: I do not understand clearly how the number of child processes to create is related to `n`. Could you, please, clarify this. (E.g. `n` is the number of processes which shall fork two children, or `n` is the total number of forked processes...)

Comment: @Scheff I am trying to generate a binary tree of processes that create 2 childs for each process and suppose im passing n=3 the process tree shuould be as below.

Comment: @Scheff            i
                         / \
                        /   \
                       /     \
                      /       \
                     /         \
                    i           i
                   / \                 
                 i     i

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get it. `n` is the number of processes which shall fork? Or: `n`is the depth of binary tree of processes formed by the forks?

Comment: @Scheff yes n is the depth of the binary tree formed by the forks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>As I assume that Raj understood `fork()` and `wait()` but did not yet get the concept of binary trees (and how to implement them using recursive functions) I made a small complete sample for this. It prevents the usage of `fork()` to make the binary tree/recursion concept more clear.</s>

Putting it altogether:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void foo()
{
  printf("child process %d, (%d)->(%d)\n",
    getpid(), getppid(), getpid());
}

/* creates child processes in binary tree manner.
 *
 * n ... number of tree nodes (child processes) to create
 */
void do_fork(int n)
{
  if (n <= 0) return;
  int n1 = n / 2;
  int n2 = n - n1;
  int pid1 = 0, pid2 = 0;
  if (n1 >= 0) {
    --n1;
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fork failed in process %d!\n", getpid());
      return;
    }
    if (pid1 == 0) { 
      foo();
      do_fork(n1);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  if (n2 >= 0) {
    --n2;
    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fork failed in process %d!\n", getpid());
      return;
    }
    if (pid2 == 0) {
      foo();
      do_fork(n2);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  wait(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n = 3; /* number of binary tree nodes, might become input */
  printf("parent process %d, children to create: %d\n", getpid(), n);
  if (n) do_fork(n);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and tested this with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ gcc -o test-bin-tree-fork test-bin-tree-fork.c

$ ./test-bin-tree-fork.exe
parent process 8628, children to create: 3
child process 13608, (8628)->(13608)
child process 7292, (8628)->(7292)
child process 8920, (7292)->(8920)
child process 14104, (7292)->(14104)
```

Comment: the code you have written is generating more than 2 or zero at times but im trying to have a binary tree of processes where if n= 4 which is even number then a parent process generates 2 child process and each child process should generate 2 child processes if n = 3 that is odd number then the binary tree process should be like one parent process generating 2 child processes and only one  of the child process should generate 2 child processes

Comment: the code you have written is generating more than 2 or zero at times but im trying to have a binary tree of processes where if n= 4 which is even number then a parent process generates 2 child process and each child process should generate 2 child processes if n = 3 that is odd number then the binary tree process should be like one parent process

Comment: @Raj I changed the sample code. I did (hopefully) match your additional specification. However, in this case `n` *is* the number of processes to fork but not the intended tree depth. (Or I oversaw that this is the same? No, I guess: not.)

Comment: yes I was wrong to think it as the depth of binary tree, you are right about the n = number of process to be forked, That's was what i was trying to do thanks for helping out

Comment: in the new code i don't find you implementing the fork() call how can we implement a fork() call and generate the same output

Comment: @Raj _You_ can mix up your solution (containing calls of `fork()`, `exit()`, and `wait()` in the correct manner as far as I saw) and my solution (where I marked the appropriate places with `/* fork would happen here */`) to the final code. The `pid` argument can be removed from `do_fork()`, of course. I used it as parent process ID for illustration only.

Comment: I managed to call the fork() but i have a problem while generating an output for process the do_for is being called twice one for real processes and one for fake process as below can you help me get rid of the fake processes in output example output:

Comment: I managed to call the fork() by just changing the statement static pid =0; to pid=fork(); but i have a problem while generating an output for process the do_fork(); is being called twice one for real processes and one for fake process as below can you help me get rid of the fake processes in output example output:

Comment: parent process 4, children to create: 4                         child process 5, (4)->(5)      |
child process 6, (5)->(6)      |
child process 7, (5)->(7)      |  --> i want to get rid of these print statements               child process 8, (4)->(8)      | 
child process 9, (8)->(9)      | 
child process 10, (8)->(10)    |     
parent process 113, children to create: 4 
child process 114, (113)->(114)  }
child process 115, (114)->(115)  }
child process 116, (114)->(116)  } ---> want these print statements
child process 117, (113)->(117)  }
child process 118, (117)->(118)  }

Comment: @Raj Congratulations. I did your homework.

Comment: I did manage to get there with your inputs by holding the if statements at the if(pid==0){exit(0);} and  if(pid > 0 ){
  printf("parent process %d, children to create: %d \n", pid, n);
} your inputs were helpful in understanding how to write a bit advance programming for me Thanks !!